# Help needed with syntax over how to make a database update from javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get my head around MVC at the moment.
What I want to do is this;

```
        function TestClickFunc(userId) {

            $.post("/Users/UpdateEmailDistributionListFlag", { id: userId });
        }
```

However I cannot use JQuery directly in a javascript method like this.
I have been hunting around for examples, but now I need to refer to you. How do I ready JQuery for this Javascript method?
I want to call the UpdateEmailDistributionListFlag method on the Users controller and send a parameter userId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link to the `js` file is broken (http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery-1.4.1.min.js), so you actually don't have `jQuery` included. Try this one instead: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1.min.js

Answer (score 1):

Dont use onclick="xxx". Horrible! Let jQuery set it all up:

```
$(function(){
  $('input:checkbox').change(function() {
    var userId = $(this).attr('userId');
    $.post("/Users/UpdateEmailDistributionListFlag", { id: userId });
  });
});
```

This will post a request to your action when the checkbox is clicked. I don't know exactly how you DOM works and I made that up on the spot just to give you the gist. By the way you sound like someone who could do with some [jQuery IntelliSense](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/08/intellisense-jquery-visual-studio-2010.html) (aren't we all?!)

This is assuming you use something like:

```
<%: Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.EmailDistributionListFlag, new { userId = Model.UserId })%>
```

I take it you have an action like this ready and waiting:

```
[HttpPost]
public void UpdateEmailDistributionListFlag(int userId)
{
  //log something
}
```

Comment: You are right about the Method being in place on the UsersController.
The Javascript method is called from the click event on a checkbox. This checkbox is rendered in a partial view within a foreach loop, hence we have a grid and this is why I have done it like this;
<%: Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.EmailDistributionListFlag, 
                    new { id = "checkBoxEmailDistributionListFlag", onclick="TestClickFunc("+ Model.UserId + ")" })%>

Comment: It should be simple to resolve, I get $ is not defined in FireBug. Now I am picking up the CDN for JQuery in my master page; <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
However I am sure there is something obvious that needs changing.

Comment: Great advice about replacing onclick! Much rather use JQuery.